How to correctly call a procedure with record parameters
I have this type declared
CREATE TYPE home77.test_record AS
(
    field character varying(50),
    value character varying(50)
);

I have a procedure with parameters of type records
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE home77.save_test_record(
    INOUT rec1 home77.test_record,
    INOUT rec2 home77.test_record)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
 insert into home77.table_test(field, value) values (rec1.field, rec1.value);
 insert into home77.table_test(field, value) values (rec2.field, rec2.value);
 commit; 
END;
$BODY$;

A SQL block:
DO
$$
declare
 rec1 home77.test_record;
 rec2 home77.test_record;
begin
 rec1.field:=@p1; 
 rec1.value:=@p2; 
 
 rec2.field:=@p3; 
 rec2.value:=@p4; 
 call home77.save_test_record(rec1, rec2);
 commit;
end;
$$

I'm using this C# code. When calling the callProc() method I get an error:
using Npgsql;
using System.Data;

namespace param_records
{
    public static class TestRecord
    {
       public static void callProc()
        {
            const string connString = @"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=5414;Search Path=home77";
            const string sql = "DO $$ declare rec1 home77.test_record; rec2 home77.test_record; begin  rec1.field:=@p1; rec1.value:=@p2; rec2.field:=@p3; rec2.value:=@p4; call home77.save_test_record(rec1, rec2); commit; end; $$";
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "field value rec1");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "value rec1");

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "field value rec2");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 50, "value rec2");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Error:  Npgsql.PostgresException: "42703: Column 'p1' does not exist"

Please suggest how to do this via SQL block. What am I doing wrong? Where is the error in the code?

you can't use parameters in a do block
